# Can Azure Key Vault Encryption Decryption be performed in Databricks?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

I have some encrypted Azure Blobs that I need to decrypt using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault?tabs=dotnet) Azure Key Vault mechanism. Is there any possibility of using Scala or Python in databricks to do this decryption? I am not sure if there are any libraries available in either of these languages that will allow me to do the decryption? If you know of any libraries or have some sample code that can work in Python or Scala, it would really help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Azure Storage Client Library for Python](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage/) supports encrypting data within client applications before uploading to Azure Storage, and decrypting data while downloading to the client.

> Use the Encryption via the **envelope technique** contains the following steps

**1)** The Azure storage client library generates a **content encryption key (CEK)**, which is a one-time-use symmetric key.

**2)**  User data is encrypted using this content encryption key (CEK)

**3)** The CEK is then wrapped (encrypted) using the **key encryption key (KEK)**. The KEK is identified by a key identifier and can be an asymmetric key pair or a symmetric key, which is managed locally. The storage client library itself never has access to KEK. The library invokes the key wrapping algorithm that is provided by the KEK. Users can choose to use custom providers for key wrapping/unwrapping if desired

**4)** The encrypted data is then uploaded to the Azure Storage service. The wrapped key along with some additional encryption metadata is either stored as metadata (on a blob) or interpolated with the encrypted data (queue messages and table entities).

> **Decryption via the envelope technique:** contains the following steps

**1)**  The client library assumes that the user is managing the key encryption key (KEK) locally. The user does not need to know the specific key that was used for encryption. Instead, a key resolver, which resolves different key identifiers to keys, can be set up and used.

**2)**  The client library downloads the **encrypted data along with any encryption material** that is stored on the service

**3)** The wrapped **content encryption key (CEK)** is then unwrapped (decrypted) using the **key encryption key (KEK)**. Here again, the client library does not have access to KEK. It simply invokes the custom provider's unwrapping algorithm

**4)**  The **content encryption key (CEK)** is then used to decrypt the encrypted user data.

For more details and step by step procedure refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-client-side-encryption-python?tabs=python)

Comment: Thanks for the document link and the link to the python library as well. Do you have any links where there is some sample code written for decryption? I found the encryption functions but nothing for decryption. Thanks again!

Comment: Please refer this github code :https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_encryption.py If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you